# Can't figure out NS_ENUM. Can I change the values inside it?

Tags: objective-c, variables, scope, nsenumerator

I am VERY new to Objective-C. I was having a problem with this :

```
NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, SetOfValues)
{ 
    firstRow = 0,
    secondRow,
    thirdRow,
    rowCount
};
```

Now, I need to change these variables in the implementations :

```
@implementation BillyBurroughs 
...

- (void) modifyrowInformation
{
    secondRow = 0;
    thirdRow = 1;
    rowCount = 2
}

@end
```

But of course, I get an error saying - cannot assign value. Now, I can simply read the variables to local variables like

```
+ (void) initialize {
    localFirstRow = 0 
    ...
}
```

and then modify them, but is there a cleaner and lazier way to do this without the extra variables? Sorry if this is a very basic question. I appreciate your inputs.

Comment: What are you trying to use these 'variables' for? Enums are constants, you can set variables to the value of an enum.

Comment: Is there a better option then to assign them? Something like :P a mutable NS_ENUM ? As for your question, the constants are being used in a million places in this class. Changing one and assigning to local variables would mean a million changes for me. So I was hoping I could abstract them to something easier.

Comment: Now, I don't want them to be static either. So apart from defining 4 properties, I can't really figure it out.

Comment: an enum is constant... period, there arent instances of enums. so it is 1000x the exact same memory location.

Comment: I would propose making the enum a class and alloc init it in each file but I really dont get what you're trying to do Im afraid.

Comment: Please clarify the question somehow

Comment: Your second last suggestion was precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enums are **constants**, you cant change their value and why do you want to? thats what ivars are for.

`NS_ENUM` is a nice macro apple gave us which expands to something like the following:

```
typedef enum {
    firstRow = 0,
    secondRow,
    thirdRow,
    rowCount,
} SetOfValues;
```

*NB:* 0 is initialised by default for the first element unless specified.

It is also good practice to namespace your enums to avoid collisions, maybe take a look at apples implementation and apply it to your own use case:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewCellStyle) {
    UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
    UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
};
```

Maybe what you are looking for is a property or an array?

```
array = @[ @1, @2, @3, @4 ];
```

---

*edit for question in comments:*

In your implementation file (.m) you can create a private header:

```
@interface OKAClass ()
  @property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger property;
@end
```

You then may access the property from within that class using `self` or `_property`

e.g.

```
self.property = 1;
```

or

```
_property = 1;
```

The difference is that the `self.property` uses the generated accessors and is probably what you want to be using, this will future proof you incase you wish to override the getter/setter to update another value.

Comment: To add to that. Any suggestions on how to make an NSUInteger property?

Comment: @gran_profaci I have updated the answer, give it a look.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using exactly what you said.